# Pigeonhole problem finding the minimum

Tags: pigeonhole-principle

There are 20 meetings. each neeting has 8 attendees. However, no pair of attendees appear more than once. What is the minimum number of people? To be more specific once a specific pair of people appear in a meeting, this pair will not appear again in any of the other meetings.

My soluton
8C2=28
So there are at leat 28×20=560 distinct pairs
Minimum number of people for there to be 560 distinct pairs= 34
But textbook ans is 35???

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: Your textbook answer is wrong; the correct answer is $49$. What book is that?

Answer (score 1):

As you calculated, the 20 meetings generate 560 pairs of people, and each pair can only appear once in all meetings.
Imagine that there was a solution with only 34 people, resulting in 561 possible pairs of people. Then apart from one pair $(p_1,p_2)$, each pair should appear exactly once. This means that there certainly is one person (for example $p_3$) who had meetings with *every* of the 33 other persons.
However, the meetings of $p_3$ should now partition all 33 people in groups of 7, but clearly this is impossible since 7 doesn't divide 33.

Of course, this reasoning does not imply that a schedule could effectively be made with 35 people.

Comment: The [Johnson bound](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Johnson_bound) implies that for $35$ people the number of meetings is at most $$\left\lfloor\frac{35}{8}\left\lfloor\frac{34}{7}\right\rfloor\right\rfloor = 17.$$

Answer (score 1):

The correct answer is $49$.

Such a configuration of meetings is impossible if there are only $48$ people. Let $n_i$ be the number of meetings attended by the $i^\text{th}$ person; so $\sum_{i=1}^{48}n_i=20\cdot8=160$. Since no two people attend the same two meetings, we must have $$\sum_{i=1}^{48}\binom{n_i}2\le\binom{20}2=190.\tag1$$ Now the quantity $\sum_{i=1}^{48}\binom{n_i}2$ is minimized, subject to the constraint $\sum_{i=1}^{48}n_i=160$, when the natural numbers $n_i$ are as nearly equal as possible, *i.e.*, they are all $3$ or $4$, so we have
$$\sum_{i=1}^{48}\binom{n_i}2\ge32\binom32+16\binom42=192\gt190=\binom{20}2$$
contradicting $(1)$.

With $49$ people we can even have $21$ meetings with each meeting attended by $8$ people and no two people meeting together more than once. To see this, consider the [projective plane](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Projective_plane) $\mathrm{PG}(2,7)$; it has $57$ points and $57$ lines, $8$ points on each line and $8$ lines through each point, any two lines intersecting in just one point. If we regard the points as "people" and the lines as "meetings", we have $57$ people and $57$ meetings. Now let $\Omega$ be a set of $8$ points such that no three are collinear; such a set exists and is called an [oval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Oval_(projective_plane)). By [the in-and-out formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inclusion%E2%80%93exclusion_principle), the number of lines incident with at least one point of $\Omega$ is $\binom81\cdot8-\binom82\cdot1=36$. Thus there are $57-36=21$ lines/meetings among the $57-8=49$ points/people not in $\Omega$.

Comment: In fact, $21$ is the maximum for $49$ people.  That is, $A(49,14,8)=21$:  https://www.win.tue.nl/~aeb/codes/Andw.html#d14